# ISP local subnet is 192.168.1.x causing issue with VPN access

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

I couldn't figure out why I was dropping a client-based VPN connection to a remote site with a `192.168.1.x` subnet until I figured out the ISPs modem is running a `192.168.1.x` subnet for their own purposes.

I would prefer not to add a routing statement on my own workstations because I foresee it causing a lot of pain and lost productivity, so I would like to add a route statement into my firewall (the gateway before my ISP's subnet) to fix the situation.

However, I have zero idea how to do this or even how to phrase the google search to get close to what I want to do. Do I want a null route statement, a statement that sends packets to loopback? Dunno but it feels like a "divide by zero" situation.

In the end, I would like any device on my internal private subnet behind my firewall to think there's no `192.168.1.0` subnet out there. That should force all the traffic over the VPN.

What can be done to fix this?

- **Internal private subnet**: `172.16.16.0`
- **Internal GW**: `172.16.16.1` (PFsense fw)
- **ISP provided internal subnet**: `10.0.10.0`
- **ISP GW**: `10.0.10.1` (VZ modem)
- **ISP provided equipment subnet**: `192.168.1.0`

Traceroute without VPN being active:

```
Tracing route to 192.168.1.1 over a maximum of 30 hops
  1     8 ms    12 ms     4 ms  kcactc-fw [172.16.16.1]
  2    10 ms     8 ms     5 ms  10.0.10.1
  3    10 ms     9 ms    13 ms  192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Seems like there is a lack of some fundamental understanding here. Where is the VPN established? Is it on the individual devices or at your firewall? Either way, devices internal to your network don’t know anything about the network beyond your firewall. To them, 192.168.1.x does NOT exist. They simply send their traffic to the default route (your firewall) and your firewall determines where to send the traffic after that. It is well known you can’t have conflicting subnets on both sides of a VPN connection. A route can’t fix that. Don’t use common subnet addressing like 192.168.1.x.

Comment: In addition that is a strange trace route and it’s not clear what you are suggesting by “isp provided equipment subnet.” This 192.168..x network is beyond even your ISP modem which means even your firewall doesn’t know it exists. So it simply can’t be that this is causing you any issue. A VPN is a tunnel protocol, meaning the two VPN endpoints know nothing about the network between, which includes 192.168.1.x.

Comment: Clarification: the 192.168.1.x network is on the modem. The 10.0.10.x subnet is the one my fw is connected to, a wired port on the back of the modem. The 192.168.1.x network is another subnet VLAN on the modem that services the tv boxes provided by Verizon (my ISP).

Comment: That clarifies some things. But my point is, there are only two places a VPN would be established on your end - either on your firewall or on one or more individual devices, such as a PC. In any case, the tunnel is established by connecting to a public IP on the internet. Once the tunnel is established the data flows directly between the two endpoints. The internal IPs are inside the tunnel. They are not affected by another network attached to your modem. I’m probably doing a terrible job explaining this, but this is not why you are having issues. Sorry.

Comment: The VPN is SonicWall Mobile Connect SSL client vpn. It originates on my host.

Comment: The traceroute looks normal with vpn disconnected. Once connected, packets destined to 192.168.1.x will not take that route. They are encapsulated in the tunnel.

Comment: , not on the firewall.  I agree, the computer shouldn’t be affected by a subnet two hops away when the vpn is connected but it sure seems to be sending some packets that way